# What's the relation between these two definition of Ackermann function?

Tags: computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

The definition 1 is from *Introduction to Algorithm* and the second is from wikipedia.
[image: [dd](!https://www.latexlive.com/#QV9rKGopJTIwPSUyMCU1Q2xlZnQlNUMlN0IlMjAlMEElNUNiZWdpbiU3QmFsaWduZWQlN0QlMEEmaisxJTIwJTIwJTVDcXVhZCUyMCZrPTAlNUMlNUMlMEEmQV8lN0JrLTElN0QlNUUlN0IoaisxKSU3RChqKSUyMCZrJTIwJTVDZ2UlMjAxJTIwJTBBJTVDZW5kJTdCYWxpZ25lZCU3RCUwQSU1Q3JpZ2h0Lg==)]

[image]

Comment: I think the top definition is meant to have $A^{(j+1)}_{k-1}(1)$. At least, if the functions are meant to be equal (which isn't a complete certainty), then that's what it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

The second form is equivalent to formular
[image]

if we let the first definiction be A and the second one be \bar{A}, then we have

[image]

Proof：

- first

[image]

since
[image]

- second

[image]

then

[image]

so

[image]

This is the only relationshift I can find.